# Add a period after each paragraph title

Tags: paragraphs

I tend to use `\paragraph{text}` to structure my text (instead of `\subsubection` for example). The text in the paragraph is printed bold and some extra spacing is inserted. I would like to alter this by having latex print a period after the bold text. I could achieve this effect by defining another macro like.

```
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1.}}
```

Is there some way to achieve the same effect using a more latex-friendly way (like a `\paragraphDelimiter` variable)?

Comment: You simply want to add a period to the paragraph title automatically?

Comment: your code fragments are so small it is impossible to guess what you are doing. `\paragraph` is a fourth level section heading following section,subsection,subsubsection. Despite its name it doesn't have much to do with paragraphs of text. You could modify the definition copied from article class (which is only a line) or use any package that helps set up section formatting.

Comment: If you load `titlesec`, then you can do `\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}[.]`. So if you write `\paragraph{A title}`, this will yield `A title.` in the resulting PDF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Copy the definition of `\paragraph` from your class (here I used `article`) and modify it by just adding `\maybe@addperiod` as shown: it should be the last token in the last argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \@addpunct

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}
    {4}
    {\z@}
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}
    {-1em}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\maybe@addperiod}%
}
\newcommand{\maybe@addperiod}[1]{%
  #1\@addpunct{.}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{This is the title} And some text follows.

\paragraph{This is the title.} And some text follows.

\paragraph{Is this is a title?} And some text follows.

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the period is printed only if punctuation doesn't end the argument to `\paragraph`.

If you want a version that doesn't need looking for the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \@addpunct

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\latexparagraph\paragraph
\RenewDocumentCommand{\paragraph}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexparagraph*{\maybe@addperiod{#3}}}
    {\latexparagraph[#2]{\maybe@addperiod{#3}}}%
}
\newcommand{\maybe@addperiod}[1]{%
  #1\@addpunct{.}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{This is the title} And some text follows.

\paragraph{This is the title.} And some text follows.

\paragraph{Is this is a title?} And some text follows.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this may be a little over-engineered, but it works. I do also like Alenannos suggestion.

Comment: @hfhc2 If you happen to have a title ending with punctuation different from a period, the simpler solution won't work.

Comment: Also check out the magisterial handling of titles `\paragraph{Like ``this.'' }`

Comment: @JoeCorneli Which should work, I guess. `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

egreg's and Alenanno's solutions are great. For a simpler one, how about the following?

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldparagraph=\paragraph
\renewcommand\paragraph[1]{\oldparagraph{#1.}}
\begin{document}

\paragraph{Hello}

World.

\end{document}
```