# Horizontal Spacing in \titlespacing

Tags: spacing, formatting, titlesec

I am using the `titlesec` package to adjust the spacing between `paragraph`-s.
My command overwrites the whitespace in the `runin` part, however, and I don't know how to retrieve it.
Compare the two parts of this image.

[image]

It is generated by the MWE below. I have happy with the *vertical* spacing in the second case---it uses `medskipamount`. However, I would like the default gap between the number and the text in the paragraph.

The [titlesec documentation](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) (Section 3.2) isn't so helpful on this matter. Any help from people here would be most appreciated!

I'd *also* like to know how to add a fullstop after the number automatically. I am not 100% decided on whether to include this or not, so I'd like an answer which explains both options.

MWE below.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

    \section{Default Behaviour}
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 1}
    with runin
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 2}
    with runin
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 3}
    with runin
    
    
    \section{New Behaviour}
    
    \titlespacing{\paragraph}
    {0pt}{\medskipamount}{\smallskipamount}[what do I write in here?]
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 1}
    with runin
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 2}
    with runin
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 3}
    with runin

\end{document}
```

---

**Update.** The solution is super easy. The length `before-sep` is the vertical space before the paragraph but, very confusingly, `after-sep` *is not* the vertical space after the paragraph! Instead, it's the *horizontal* space after the *title*.

Pretty crazy use of terminology, but hey, hopefully this question will now be helpful to others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}

    \section{Default Behaviour}
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 1}
    with runin
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 2}
    with runin
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 3}
    with runin
    
    \section{New Behaviour}
    \titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{\medskipamount}{*2.5}
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 1}
    with runin
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 2}
    with runin
    
    \paragraph*{Paragraph 3}
    with runin
\end{document}
```

[image]

See
[Add a period after each paragraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328355/add-a-period-after-each-paragraph-title) for information about
attaching a period to each paragraph title.

Comment: Ah, I'm dumb! I assumed that `before-sep` and `after-sep` were complimentary, since the names suggest this, and didn't read them carefully. But they aren't: the former is vertical spacing and the latter horizontal. It is much more natural for `right` to mean "spacing to the right", but oh well. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @SamOT, you are welcome!

Comment: Incidentally, is `*2.5`, ie `2.5ex plus 0.25ex`, the default? One thing that I hate about so many latex packages is that the authors forget to write what the defaults are...