# Automatically add a final period if argument of '\paragraph' does not end with a punctuation character

Tags: punctuation

I'd like to automatically add a final period if the argument of `\paragraph` does not end with either `.`, `?`, or `!`.

A solution has been provided in [Add a period after each paragraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328355) but this requires the last letter not being an upper case. How to address the general case?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \@addpunct

\makeatletter
\let\latexparagraph\paragraph
\RenewDocumentCommand{\paragraph}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexparagraph*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\latexparagraph{\maybe@addperiod{#3}}}
       {\latexparagraph[#2]{\maybe@addperiod{#3}}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\maybe@addperiod}[1]{%
  #1\@addpunct{.}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    
\paragraph{This is the title} And some text follows.

\paragraph{This is the title.} And some text follows.

\paragraph{Is this is a title?} And some text follows.

\paragraph{This is the title X} And some text follows.

\paragraph{This is the title X.} And some text follows.

\paragraph{Is this is a title X?} And some text follows.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A capital letter should be marked with `\@` if you expect punctuation to follow and it's not an abbreviation.

Comment: Please advise if you might ever use `\paragraph` with an optional argument, e.g., `\paragraph[Title]{This is the title}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expressions. Here I check whether the argument ends with ‘!’, ‘?’ or ‘.’ and, if not, a period is added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy\latexparagraph\paragraph
\RenewDocumentCommand{\paragraph}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexparagraph*{\maybeaddperiod{#3}}}
    {\latexparagraph[#2]{\maybeaddperiod{#3}}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\maybeaddperiod}{m}
 {
  \userninefourtwoninethree_maybeaddperiod:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \userninefourtwoninethree_maybeaddperiod:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { .*[\!\?\.] \Z } { #1 } { #1 } { #1. }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    
\paragraph{This is the title} And some text follows.

\paragraph{This is the title.} And some text follows.

\paragraph{Is this is a title?} And some text follows.

\paragraph{This is the title X} And some text follows.

\paragraph{This is the title X.} And some text follows.

\paragraph{Is this is a title X?} And some text follows.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway, the previous solution works if you take the habit of adding `\@` after any trailing uppercase letter that's not an abbreviation.

Comment: +1. You may also want to strip off any trailing whitespace in the argument of `\paragraph`, to deal with cases such as `\paragraph{This is the title  }`.

Comment: @Mico No, that's something nobody should have in their document.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. Also added the case of the ":"; `\regex_match:nnTF { .*[\!\?\.\:] \Z } { #1 } { #1 } { #1. }`

Answer (score 8):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It works by examining the argument of `\paragraph` and making use of Lua's powerful `find`, `gsub`, and `sub` string functions. If no punctuation mark is present at the end of the string, a period is inserted. As a (likely minor) bonus, this solution works with both `\paragraph` and `\paragraph*` directives.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode*' environment
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
function doit ( u , v ) -- aux. function that does most of the work
  v = v:sub ( 1, -2 )        -- strip off closing curly brace
  v = v:gsub ( "%s+$" , "" ) -- strip off any trailing whitespace
  w = v:sub ( -1 )           -- retrieve last char in 'v' string
  if ( w=="." or w=="?" or w=="!" ) then
  else
    v = v.."." -- add period to end of 'v' string
  end
  return u .. v .. "}" -- add back the closing curly brace
end
function maybeaddperiod ( s )      -- the main function
  if s:find ( "\\paragraph" ) then -- we need to do something...
    return s:gsub ( "(\\paragraph%*?)%s*(%b{})" , doit )
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}
% Add the Lua function to LuaTeX's "process_input_buffer" callback:
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
   "process_input_buffer" , maybeaddperiod, "maybeaddperiod" )}}

\begin{document} 
%% Insert period at end of arg of "\paragraph"
\paragraph{This is the title } And some text follows.
\paragraph{This is the title X} And some text follows.
\paragraph*{This is the title } And some text follows.

\bigskip
%% Don't insert period
\paragraph{This is the title. } And some text follows.
\paragraph{Is this the title?} And some text follows.
\paragraph{This is the title! } And some text follows. 
\end{document}
```