# Automatically add a final period to a caption where there is none

Tags: captions, punctuation

I tried to adapt the answer to [Automatically add a final period if argument of '\paragraph' does not end with a punctuation character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685660/) as a way to automatically add a period to a caption when there is none. For reasons I don't understand, this does not work out of the box. What is wrong (see Fig. 3)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{addpunct}{\maybeaddperiod{#1}}
\captionsetup{textformat=addpunct}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\maybeaddperiod}{m}
 {
  \userninefourtwoninethree_maybeaddperiod:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \userninefourtwoninethree_maybeaddperiod:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { .*[\!\?\.\:] \Z } { #1 } { #1 } { #1. }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}
  \caption{This is an image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is image A}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
  \caption{This is image B.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `\tl_show:n{#1}` in the code for `\userninefourtwoninethree_maybeaddperiod:n`, you will see that the first call shows

```
> \ignorespaces \caption@makeanchor {This is an image}.
```

For its purposes, `caption` wraps the actual caption text as an argument to `\caption@makeanchor`.

You see that the argument examined by `\maybeaddperiod` *never* ends with a period, but always with a `}`.

Change into

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \userninefourtwoninethree_maybeaddperiod:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { .*[\!\?\.\:] \} \Z } { #1 } { #1 } { #1. }
 }
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{addpunct}{\maybeaddperiod{#1}}
\captionsetup{textformat=addpunct}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\maybeaddperiod}{m}
 {
  \userninefourtwoninethree_maybeaddperiod:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \userninefourtwoninethree_maybeaddperiod:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { .*[\!\?\.\:] \} \Z } { #1 } { #1 } { #1. }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}
  \caption{This is an image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is image A}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
  \caption{This is image B.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The following code shows how we can remove optional dot from the end of the argument of a macro and then we can add single period to the output. All is done only by TeX primitive commands.

```
\def\maybeaddperiod #1{\mbaddperiodA #1\empty.\empty\end}
\def\mbaddperiodA #1.\empty #2\end{#1.}

\maybeaddperiod{Text}        % prints: Text.

\maybeaddperiod{Foo. Bar.}   % prints: Foo. Bar.
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice trick. It however adds an unwanted period when there is a punctation different from "."; e.g., `\maybeaddperiod{Text!}` produces Text!.

Comment: @user94293 You can remove the `!.` and `?.` pair from the argument by very similar trick. I leave this as an exercise for the reader.