How to make sections inside the Abstract
My paper was rejected because I didn't adhere to the "International Journal of Medical Informatics" standards for the Abstract section.
I searched extensively but couldn’t find their template specifying how to format section names in the Abstract.
Are these sections simply italicized, or is there a specific name for this formatting style?


For my info: What do you submit? .pdf, .tex? Other? Thank you

Unfortunately I couldn't find any LaTeX template

Useful page: Guide for Authors under section "Writing and formatting" > "Abstract"

IMHO it is very strange to reject an article only because it does not adhere to the "guidelines for the abstract", which, btw are not well defined: at the top of the page the length of the abstract is up to 300 words for articles, while down at the relevant section it is up to 250. So, unless your abstract was like more than 500 words, the article should not have been rejected. Especially not for formatting, since the publisher will do the final typesetting.

Looking at an article in the last issue of the journal, there's nothing particular to be done in order to have a structured abstract.
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{This is a the title}
\author{Abigail Uthor}
\ead{A.Uthor@someuni.edu}
\affiliation{
  organization=Some University,
  city=Town,
  country=Some,
}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent\emph{Introduction.} This is the introduction. \lipsum[1][1-4]

\noindent\emph{Objective.} \lipsum[3][1-6]

\noindent\emph{Methods.} \lipsum[4][1-4]
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\lipsum

\end{document}


Compare with an image from an article in the last issue (only partial to just show the beginning of lines):


It seems they are simple paragraphs. Here's an example of how you can redefine the paragraph style in the article class:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}% for \@addpunct
\usepackage{lipsum}% for \dummy text

% Redefine paragraph for italicized section headers
% code shameless copied from @egreg answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328358/127473
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\em\maybe@addperiod}}
                                    % {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}% <- original definition
\newcommand{\maybe@addperiod}[1]{%
    #1\@addpunct{.}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Abstract}

\paragraph{Introduction}
\lipsum[1][1-5]

\paragraph{Objective}
\lipsum[1][1-5]

\paragraph{Methods}
\lipsum[1][1-5]

\end{document}

